# NSMutableArray vs NSArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios, xcode

i have created a script, witch load the XML from server parse it an save it to NSMutableArray

```
[kategorienArray addObject:catName];
```

catName ist a String, if i NSLog the Array everything works fine.

After that i have created a tebleview, and reload Data

```
[kategorienAuswahl reloadData];
```

KategorienAuswahl is my TableView

and now a get the Problems

if i Use a "normal" array

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPhone", @"iPod", @"iPad",nil];
    self.listData = array;
    [array release];
```

the will be displayed, but if i use

```
cell.textLabel.text = [kategorienArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

instead it works fine with

```
cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
```

I Add nwo

```
kategorienArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    kategorienArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
```

but now i get no data in my Tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not have initialized your `kategorienArray`.
Do you have a `kategorienArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in your code? You should have done this before adding objects to it and then accessing them.

Also, make sure your array is retained at the point where it's created, so that the system doesn't reclaim its memory before you access its items. The way I use to make sure things are going right is to declare the mutable array as a property. In your viewcontroller's .h file put

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *kategorienArray;
```

and in your .m file put

```
@synthesize kategorienArray;
```

at the top and then

```
self.kategorienArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere, before adding items to it.

Comment: Put some NSLog statements after adding each item to make sure that you actually do add data (that part of the code is executed) and that your array is being added to: NSLog(@"%d", [kategorienArray count]);

Comment: Great news! Please consider accepting the answer if you consider it to solve you problem.

Comment: @luvieere i fixed a memory leak in your code (assuming non-GC and non-ARC)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that 'kategorienArray' has been (auto)released.
Is 'kategorienArray' an ivar ?
Check out if when you created the array you correctly retained it (particularly if you created it with a class method).